# Rails: a DRY way to add the same `belongs_to` statement for a relatively large number of models

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a rails app that has a number of models, all of which have a `user_id` field and need to belong to the `User` model because I would like to see which user authored which record for authorization purposes using ActiveAdmin.

Anyways, I am trying to find a DRY way to add this `belongs_to :user` statement to all the models. I tried creating a concern module (?) `BelongsToUser` but could not make it work. I have also looked into model inheritance (STI) but I don't think it is suitable to my situation.

Here is my `BelongsToUser` concern:

```
module BelongsToUser 
    extend ActiveSupport::Concern

    belongs_to :user

end
```

Here is how I include it in my models:

```
class ModelName < ApplicationRecord
   # Other Stuff

   include BelongsToUser

   # Other stuff

end
```

I get the following error:

> undefined method `belongs_to' for BelongsToUser:Module

Comment: If it's just one line you want to `DRY`-up then a concern or an include doesn't really save any code since you have to spend the line including the concern anyway.

Comment: @okay56k You are absolutely right! But I might need to change that concern (if that is the answer) in the future, and I want to only make my changes in one place.

Comment: _I tried creating a concern module (?) but could not make it work_ What did you try? And why it didn't work?

Comment: @SebastianPalma Thank you for pointing this out. I have added the code and  the error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simple version of the module is this:

```rb
module BelongsToUser
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  included do 
    belongs_to :user
  end
end

class ModelName < ApplicationRecord
  include BelongsToUSer
end
```

Of course, this only make sense if you're doing something more complex than `belongs_to :user`, otherwise you're merely moving the statement instead of DRYing up logic, for example if you need a hefty amount of boilerplate to create the association.

Another approach is to add a class method (“macro”) to `ApplicationRecord`:

```rb
class ApplicationRecord < ActiveRecord::Base
  self.abstract_class = true

  def self.user_owned
    belongs_to :user
  end
end

class ModelName < ApplicationRecord
  user_owned
end
```

Same caveats apply, though.